What is the difference between "pasar vergüenza" and "sentir vergüenza"?
What do 'pasar vergüenza" and "sentir vergüenza" mean exactly, and how do you know when to use each?
Example 1


No he pasado más vergüenza en la vida.
No he sentido más vergüenza en la vida.


Example 2


Fui a una fiesta vestida con un traje de disfraz y la fiesta no era de disfraces, mas pase vergüenza al ir así.
No pude haber sentido más vergüenza ese día que llegué a la fiesta me vieron todos mis amigos



Nadie sabe cuándo hay que usar una o cuándo hay que usar otra. La vida es eso; el que cree que todo viene de por sí clasificable, como si se pudiese reducir a meros  compartimentos estancos es realmente un iluso. Ambas frases van a ser intercambiables en el 99% de los casos. No me preocuparía por saber cuál es la correcta, asumiendo que exista algo así como una que es la correcta en cada situación. Pasar vergüenza y sentir vergüenza se implican la mayoría de las veces.

"Sentir vergüenza" refers only to your inner feelings and thoughts.
For example, you "feel" embarrassed/ashamed independently of others knowing what's happening with you.
Some examples may be:

You know something is wrong with your underwear and you feel embarrassed about it.
You feel embarrassed because you forgot the name of the person that you just meet.
Thousands of other situations.

But you "pasar una vergüenza" when that situation gots exposed. Taking the last examples:

You're wearing a skirt and your underwear slips trough your legs and someone/all the people around you notice it happened
You have to introduce this person to someone else who is just joining the conversation and you have to ask for her/his name again or, tryng to avoid it, you have said the wrong name.

In those situations you "pasas una vergüenza" ante las otras personas.
In this case, pasar is used as a transitive verb and means "to suffer":


tr. sufrir (‖ tolerar).



pasar vergüenza = to experience shame.
sentir vergüenza=to feel shame or ashamed
If you really want to see a difference there.
